# Unknown $modalProvider provider when requiring controller

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, modal-dialog, angular-strap

I'm using angularjs and requirejs to load my controllers only when they are needed.

In one of my controllers I'm using angularstraps $modal for modal boxes.

In myCtrl1 you can find the functions which close and open the modal box.

In myCtrl2 I am requiring modal.js only if the controller is referenced on the page but it looks its failing to be able to reference $modal and returns the error:

```
Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal
```

**Plunkr here: [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/1KHkKXl2mhcCzXvoUT0j?p=preview)**

Main files are index.html, controllers.js and modal.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like angularstrap's directives have not been loaded - somewhere you need to add them to the app, e.g. `var app = angular.module('myapp', ['$strap.directives']);`